# What sort of return type does nHibernate use? List<T>?

Tags: nhibernate

I want to create my database layer so I can swap it out and use say LINQ or whatever in the future.

In my abstract class (or interface), what return type should I use for results that return a list/collection of items?

Does nHibernate return List?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `IList<T>`. NHibernate always returns an `IList<T>` from it's collections and the documentation says:

> The names of the collection mappings
>   is one obvious place where the
>   differences between Java and .NET are
>   shown. Java's collection library has
>   many more options than
>   System.Collection does.
>
> ```
> * The <list> maps directly to an IList.
> * The <map> maps directly to an IDictionary.
> * The <bag> maps to an IList. A <bag> does not completely comply with
> ```
>
> the IList interface because the Add()
>   method is not guaranteed to return the
>   correct index. An object can be added
>   to a  without initializing the
>   IList. Make sure to either hide the
>   IList from the consumers of your API
>   or make it well documented.
>       * The  maps to an Iesi.Collections.ISet. That interface
>   is part of the Iesi.Collections
>   assembly distributed with NHibernate.

Not only that, it's generally good practice to code against an interface, not an abstraction.